# How to prove that the weighted $l_1$ norm enhance the sparsity more than the traditional $l_1$norm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, matrix-norms

The weighted $l_1$ norm minimization can enhance the sparsity performance in comparison with traditional $l_1$ norm minimization, that is $$ \min_{x\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}} ||wx||_1  > \min_{x\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}} ||x||_1, $$

where $A>B$ denotes that the entry $A$ has much more sparsity than the entry $B$.

How can I prove this in case the weights are from the derivative of the function $\phi(x)=\frac{x}{x+\epsilon}$, $\epsilon>0$?

Thank you.

Comment: You need to state clearly how the weights are chosen. You have not done so.

Comment: Thank you Mark. The weights are $\frac{\epsilon}{(x+\epsilon)^2}$.

Comment: Unless there are constraints you haven't told us about, or another (additive) term in the objective function, the optimal solution, for the weighted or unweighted problem, is all zeros. That is as sparse as you can get, and the weighted is not more sparse. So I suspect there's more to the problem than you have told us.

Comment: No, that is all I have. You can see this paper https://www.researchgate.net/publication/313760968_Analyzing_the_Weighted_Nuclear_Norm_Minimization_and_Nuclear_Norm_Minimization_based_on_Group_Sparse_Representation they used the log function, in my case I want to use  $\psi(x)$ as I defined it in the question.

Comment: What you showed is not at all what is in the paper. There is another term in the objective function (the "main" term). And the paper states the result regarding use of the nuclear norm, not the one-norrm. So yes, there is another addiitive term in the objective function, and the reguiarization term uses a different norm than you said.

Comment: I am sorry as I just copied the link for the wrong paper. Here is the right link https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/papers/pdf/rwl1.pdf

Comment: That problem has linear equality constraints, which render my example inapplicable. So you did not show us a very important part of the problem. As for the proof, it appears to only be in the pudding. There are numerical example provided, but no proof.